# Loading multiple views with same instance of View Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Can any one help on suggesting how to load multiple instances of similar XIBS with same instance of View Controller in COCOA / COCOA Touch?

Comment: Please provide proper comment for down vote

Comment: Nice question. I think it should work. As we use same viewController for iPad & iPhone (different XIBs). it should work for other XIBs too.. i'll give it a try & let you know

Answer (score 0):

Noooooooo… We can't use same instance of ViewController for different XIBs. ViewController is just a class. If it is used by multiple XIBs, individual objects are created for each XIBs. So definitely we can use same class, but not same instance. Hope i am clear here.